# How to Center a Menu Div in a Fixed Column Div

Tags: menu, center

I'm having a bit of trouble with something I think should be fairly easy.  (I apologize if I don't format this, or ask the question, correctly.  This is my first time asking on this site.)

Basically what I am looking to do is center my navigation menu (#homepageMenu) in the fixed width column I've set up.  I though can't for the life of me get it to center automatically using "margin 0 auto" and other things I've tried.

Below you can find the html code I'm using and the CSS. (It's probably pretty messed up since I've been playing around with everything I can think of.

Thanks for any help!

```
 <HTML>
<body>

<div id="container">
<div class="fixedwidth">

    <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <div id="logo">
    <img src="IMAGES/James%20Ross%20Beitzel.png" />
    </div>
    </a>

<div id="homepageMenu">
       <ul>
        <li>Photography</li>
        <li>Video</li>
        <li>Design</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li style="border-right:none">Strengths</li>
    </ul>
</div> 

</div>   
</div>
</body>


<CSS>
body{
margin: 0px;
min-height: 100%;
}

.fixedwidth{
position: relative;
width:600px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-bottom: 100%;
}

#logo{
position:relative;
display: block;
padding-top: 45px;
}

#logo img{
position: relative;
width: 600px;
display:block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#homepageMenu {
float:center;   
}

#homepageMenu ul{
position:relative;
width: 600px;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#homepageMenu li{
font-family: arial;
position: relative;
color: orange;
display:inline-block;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
float: left;
border-right: 1px solid black;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your CSS to the following:

```
#homepageMenu {
text-align:center;
}

#homepageMenu ul{
display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem: `#homepageMenu` takes up the whole page, so it doesn't look like it's centered (even though it is). Use `display: inline-block`, and it will shrink to fit the contents. Go to the contents, and get rid of `width: 600px` in the `ul` element.

The next problem is that `margin: auto` doesn't center inline-block elements. So instead, go to the fixed-width element, and use `text-align: center`. That should do it.

Alternatively, use `display: block` and `margin: auto` on `#homepageMenu`, and give it smaller width.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zk9dndLx/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Fantastic!  Worked like a charm.  Thanks for the quick and clear instructions!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a lot of styles in there that don't need to be there. Here's what I came up with that worked: (I removed the logo and link to get a better idea of what was going on)

```
Styles:
    .fixedwidth{
        width:600px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    #homepageMenu {
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        list-style: none;
        width: 400px;
    }

    #homepageMenu li{
        font-family: arial;
        color: orange;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        float: left;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
Html:
 <body>
    <div class="fixedwidth">
        <ul id="homepageMenu">
        <li>Photography</li>
        <li>Video</li>
        <li>Design</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Strengths</li>
        </ul>
    </div>   
</body>
```

I hope this helps!